# R language Post (with json) error: 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: r, json, post, asp.net-core-webapi, rstudio

I have created a web api using ASP.NET. The api only utilizes POST, receiving a json as a body.The web api works fine with Postman but I have problems using it with R.

A post with json using RStudio I get the error : Client error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.

Where is the error?

The verbose ( with code) from R studio is:

```
query = list(datarunID = "4",action = "CLIENTGETJOB",TreeRecordId = "73",result = "dfd")
> ListJSON = toJSON(query,pretty = FALSE,auto_unbox = TRUE)
> ListJSON
{"datarunID":"4","action":"CLIENTGETJOB","TreeRecordId":"73","result":"dfd"} 
> url1 <- "http://localhost:29999/api/cycle"
> r <- POST(url = url1,body = ListJSON,encode = "json",verbose(data_out = TRUE, data_in = TRUE, info = TRUE) )
*  Connected to localhost (::1) port 29999 (#3)
-> POST /api/cycle HTTP/1.1
-> Host: localhost:29999
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.3.3 httr/1.4.4
-> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Length: 76
>> {"datarunID":"4","action":"CLIENTGETJOB","TreeRecordId":"73","result":"dfd"}
*  upload completely sent off: 76 out of 76 bytes
<- HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
<- Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<- Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
<- Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
<- X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
<- Date: Thu, xxxxx GMT
<<  af
<<  {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"00-67xxxxxxxxa537c45-00"}
```

The Json that works with Postman is :

```
{
    "datarunID":"4",
    "action":"CLIENTGETJOB",
    "TreeRecordId" : "73",
    "result" : "dfd"
}
```

Comment: Get rid of this  `Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8` part from your request in `R`, which would certainly resolve your issue.

Comment: By the way, attach your controller code as well for better clarity. In addition, include your R code snippet for this post request.